# how to upload the doc file from registration page in php

Tags: php

I want to upload the doc files in the registration page after submitting the details has to save in database and the doc file in a folder can any one help.

Comment: did you try anything yet?

Comment: post your code that you have tried so far.

Comment: yes registration form completed i struck during database creation

Comment: what is issue you are facing with data base creation?

Comment: how can i create the table for doc column

Answer (score 1):

Try this link, [demo](http://techstream.org/Web-Development/PHP/Single-File-Upload-With-PHP)

```
<?php
// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("example.com","peter","abc123","my_db");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

if(isset($_FILES['image'])){
    $errors= array();
    $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $file_size =$_FILES['image']['size'];
    $file_tmp =$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    $file_type=$_FILES['image']['type'];   
    $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['image']['name'])));
    $extensions = array("jpeg","jpg","png");        
    if(in_array($file_ext,$extensions )=== false){
     $errors[]="extension not allowed, please choose a JPEG or PNG file."
    }
    if($file_size > 2097152){
    $errors[]='File size must be excately 2 MB';
    }               
    if(empty($errors)==true){
        move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"images/".$file_name);
        echo "Success";
    }else{
        print_r($errors);
    }
}
?>
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="image" />
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```